# NoReverseMatch for only 1 entry

Tags: django

I cannot seem to figure out what's going on here. I am getting a NoReverseMatch for only 1 item but all other similar items work just fine. Here's the traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line  139, in get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 82, in rendered_content
    content = template.render(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 140, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 134, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 840, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 854, in  render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line  123, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 134, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 840, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 854, in     render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 840, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 854, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 305, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 840, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 854, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 203, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render(context))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 447, in render
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 433, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=context.current_app)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 509, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 429, in _reverse_with_prefix
    (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns))
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'john-view' with arguments '()' and keyword  arguments '{u'sam': 4321, u'john_version': u'.1'}' not found. 1 pattern(s)  tried: ['app/(?P<sam>\\d+)/john/view/(?P<john_version>\\d+\\.\\d+)/$']
```

Here are the URLs

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$',
        SamView.as_view(),
        name='Sam-view',
    )

url(r'^(?P<Sam>\d+)/John/view/(?P<John_version>\d+\.\d+)/$',
        JohnViewer.as_view(),
        name='john-view',
    )
```

The URL for any similar entry is `/app/123/ or /app/1234/ etc.` But for this specific entry, it's returning a 500 error (The traceback is from logs) and seems to be picking up the 2nd URL whereas it should be picking up the 1st one - as in `/app/4321`. Both the URLs work for everything else.

Please let me know if you need any other information. Thanks.

Here's the SamView

```
class SamViewView(LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Samtbl
    template_name= 'John_details.html'
    permission_required = 'app.view_sam'

    @cache_control(no_cache=True, no_store=True, must_revalidate=True, max_age=0)
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(SamtView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SamView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        something =  
        Somethingtbl.objects.filter(samid=self.object.id).exclude(enabled=1)
        context['something'] = sorted(something, key=operator.attrgetter('number'))
        context['reports'] = JOhntbl.objects.filter(tid=self.object.id)
        for finding in context['something']:
             something.severity = ONE_CHOICES[something.severity]
             something.status = TWO_CHOICES[unicode(something.status)]
        return context
```

Here's JohnViewer

```
class JohnViewer(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'report_view.html'

    @cache_control(no_cache=True, no_store=True, must_revalidate=True, max_age=0)
   def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(JohnViewer, self).get(*args, **kwargs)
        self.object = Samtbl.objects.get(id = self.kwargs['sam'])
        checker = ObjectPermissionChecker(self.request.user)
        if checker.has_perm('view_sam', self.object):
            if self.kwargs.has_key('pdf'):
                return self.pdf_view(self.request)
            context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
            if self.kwargs.has_key('draft'):
                self.template_name = 'john_draft.html'
                return self.pdf_view(self.request)
            return self.render_to_response(context)
        else:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(JohnViewer, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        self.sam = Samtbl.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['sam'])
        self.sam.type = SOME_CHOICES[self.sam.type]
        something_list = Somethingtbl.objects.filter(samid=self.sam.id).exclude(enabled=1)
        self.something = sorted(something_list, key=operator.attrgetter('number')) 
        for something in self.something:
            something.severity = SOME_CHOICES[something.severity]
            something.status = SOME_OTHER_CHOICES[something.status]
            something.details = set_inline_images(something.id, finding.details)
        user_name = self.sam.get_username()
        group_list = user_name.groups.values_list('name')
        for group_name in group_list:
            for vendor in VENDOR_LIST:
                if group_name[0] == vendor:
                    vendor_list = {'so-and-so'}
                    context['organization'] = vendor_list[vendor]
        context['sam'] = self.sam
        context['john'] = johntbl.objects.get(
                                version=self.kwargs['john_version'], 
                                tid=self.kwargs['sam'])
        context['something'] = self.something
        context['john_status'] = 'final'
        return context
```

The sam-view template has a lot of links in it. One of which is john-view - `<button><a href="{% url 'john-view' sam=samtbl.id john_version=john.version.strip %}" target="_blank">HTML</a></button>`. There is no 'reverse' in either of the 2 Views.

Comment: can u post your views?

Comment: This isn't clear at all. The error says you're requesting john-view, not Sam-view.

Comment: @levi - added the views.

Comment: @DanielRoseman - That's correct. It should be requesting Sam-view but it's saying it couldn't find john-view. This is happening for that one 'sam' item alone. For every other 'sam' item, it is sam-view.

Comment: But where is that request being made? You've posted that whole view but there is no `reverse` call anywhere in it. Is it maybe coming from a `{% url %}` template tag somewhere? In which case you should post that.

Comment: @DanielRoseman - added some template info in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue. Checked the DB and `John_version` was set as  `.1` . But the `john-view` URL is

```
url(r'^(?P<Sam>\d+)/John/view/(?P<John_version>\d+\.\d+)/$',
    JohnViewer.as_view(),
    name='john-view',
    )
```

Changed it to `0.1` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You `Sam get view` should be

```
def get(self, request,pk):
    print "PK",pk # here is your  id
    return super(SamtView, self).get(request, pk)
```

I don't know why you are using positional(*args) and named arguments(**kwargs) ? You url is not catching them. Your url is just passing one positional argument named `pk`

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$',
        SamView.as_view(),
        name='Sam-view',
    )
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to have anything to do with the question.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes, because, OP url rule has pk parameter,  and in his view is not catching it.

Comment: @levi - The solution works on my local server. But my local server doesn't have that particular item. I'll have to wait before I get access to the target server and try it. But why is it working for every other item except this one?